# Can we use iOS framework like coremotion in c++ code

Tags: c++, ios, core-motion, ios-frameworks

I need to build a library in C++, which have to get data from motion sensors. And then library in both android and iOS. It looks like it is possible to do it for android but I am struggling to find an answer for iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be needing bridges for ios and android separately. Like for android you need different wrapper / JNI Bridge and different wrapper for ios Objective-c (.mm) files to used the sensor values. Ofcourse you can't share the sensor its different for each platform.

You can check this open source repository to get an idea how the wrappers around C++ and obj-c / Swift can be used.

https://github.com/foundry/OpenCVSwiftStitch

Answer (score 1):

You can use C++ with iOS. The most typical way to do this is through hybrid "Objective-C++" files (.mm), which can compile C++ functionality in an Objective-C wrapper, but you can also use straight C/C++ source and C/C++ libraries. If you want your iOS app to be written in Swift (recommended), it can still use such code - I recommend wrapping the C++ in Objective-C(++) and calling the Objective-C wrappers from Swift with a bridging header.

Comment: I have fair idea of .mm files, but I need to use iOS/Android native frameworks in c++ files.  So I can have shared files across iOS and android while accessing sensor values in c++. Any example would be very helpful

Comment: You can include your cross-platform C++ files, but then wrap the C++ classes from .mm files to make them available to Objective-C code generally. There are more ways to do this than can fit in the scope of an answer here - it really gets into design patterns like adapter and bridge, and there are also memory-management and exception-handling issues that require some study. But it's possible, and frequently done for cross-platform libraries. If you get to more specific questions you can probably find answers here, or post them for more detailed answers.

Comment: @Haris you would be needing bridges for ios and android separately. Like for android you need different wrapper / JNI Bridge and different wrapper for ios Objective-c (.mm) files to used the sensor values. Ofcourse you can't share the sensor its different for each platform. In simple words you can write 2 different adapters and use it in c++ files accordingly .